# Multiple object managers in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

How is this accomplished now a'days?

I know of that you used to do it with retain:

```
RKObjectManager *flickrManager = 
[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:flickrBaseUrl]; // <-- shared singleton

RKObjectManager *foursquareManager = 
[[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:foursquareBaseUrl] retain]; // <-- you must retain every other instance
```

But since you don't use retain anymore, what do you do?

Currently, I have 2 object managers that I'm sending off, but I only receive 1 response. I'm guessing that one of the requests is canceling the other.

**UPDATE**

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://iphone.meer.li"];
RKObjectManager *designObjectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
//...Mapping design here...
RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[designObjectManager baseURL] resourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@.json", subUrl]];
[designObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [URL resourcePath]] delegate:self];

RKObjectManager *designerObjectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];     
RKObjectMapping *designerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DesignerData class] ];
//...Mapping designer here...

RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[designerObjectManager baseURL] resourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@.json", subUrl]];
[designerObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [URL resourcePath]] delegate:self];
```

So this is my real code. I don't get why it is failing, since the objectmanagers should be retained with ARC.

Any suggestions?

Comment: They should both be retained under MRC because all convenience constructors are autoreleased.  That's why one of your requests is failing.

Comment: The above is not my real code, it's the suggestion from the Restkit website. I've posted my code above in the update. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use

```
RKObjectManager *designerObjectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
```

any more.

See the line "The first object manager you create will be the shared singleton RestKit uses by default. But by creating additional object managers, you can pull from their BaseURLs as needed, just be sure to retain these new managers" in the [RestKit Wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-Multiple-Base-URLs-%28and-Multiple-Object-Managers%29).

Answer (score 0):

Your designObjectManager is in local scope of method(from where you are sending request). It is getting released by ARC as soon as scope ends. You can make designObjectManager as instance variable of class or property.

Comment: I also tried making the two object managers into instance variables, but with no luck. It still only loads one of the objectmanagers objects. It's really weird, since it is calling -(void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects; twice, but haven't got any objects the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was making the request on the same object loader.

Answer and explanation is to be found here: [Objects not loading on second request in Restkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443919/objects-not-loading-on-second-request-in-restkit)